# Difference between be interviewing for a job vs being interviewed for a job

Tags: verb-forms, grammaticality-in-context

Here is the situation:
I have been doing a part-time English course for some months to improve my English but, I am not sure, somehow I can feel that our English teacher is not good enough. She does not speak English but has been hired to teach us English.
She has given some job interview tips to us, because the course is getting near the end. But I will not be looking for a new job even after this English course because some of you have already known that I am an assistant of ABC cake shop.

In the job interview tips briefing, she said, "If you are interviewing for a teaching job, you should be wearing a nice panty and dress."

Here is the question because of the given situation:

It was very confusing on hearing "If you are interviewing for a teaching job...", and even for the moment I am still confused about it , because we are interviewees, not any interviewers.

Please, can you tell me if the following sentences are correct, or her sentence was incorrect?
(1), "If you are going for an interview for a teaching job..."
(2), "If you are being interviewed for a teaching job..."

Comment: "Interviewing for a job" or ["Interviewing with a company"](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9706/the-are-you-interviewing-with-any-other-companies-question) is a common way of saying it.

Comment: "Interviewing for a teaching job" sounds unnatural. Out of the two you wrote, the first one sounds the best.

Comment: @Riley Francisco, I disagree, I think "interviewing for a hardware position" sounds exactly how people in Sillicon Valley would say it.

Comment: "Interviewing for a (insert detailed type of position here)" is fine, just with "teaching job" it sounds strange.

Comment: BTW, the teacher probably meant "pantyhose". "panties" (this needs to be plural, same as *pants*) is a bit too personal...

Comment: Interviewing for a teaching **position** sounds much better. I guess it was teaching followed by job that makes it sound so awkward.

Comment: You may be interested to ask a question about "wearing a nice panty" because I think it means something different than what your teacher expects. *Panties* are women's underwear. Did your teacher mean to say "wearing nice pants or a dress"? Or something else?

Comment: @Riley, what about 'teaching-related work'? (this may be uncommon though)

Comment: @shin Yes, I think that works.

Comment: @ErikE In British English "pants" means underwear, I think they call pants "trousers".

Comment: @Paul True! I knew that but didn't recall it to mind. I do know "never talk to an Englishman about his pants."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both **job** and **position** are correct. But "teaching position" sounds better.

A **Job** is a general term which is a collection of tasks that can be performed by a number of employees. A "position" is specific to its
role and responsibilities ***and can only be held by one appointed person***.

Example:

> **Job**: Manager (generic term)
>   **Position**: Finance Manager, HR Manager.
>
> My friend and I are both Managers. We have the same job. But, my position is HR manager, while his position is Finance Manager.

This is the reason why we tend to prefer "position" when talking about specific role/position/job.

So,

> 1. Interviewing for a teaching position.
> 2. Interviewing for a sales position.
> 3. Interviewing for a particular position.
> 4. Interviewing for a new job.
> 5. Interviewing for a job

All of the above sentences are correct.

And I agree with others. Your teacher probably said "[pantyhose](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pantyhose)" because "[panties](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/panties)" is too personal. And if you heard her right saying "panties," her English is definitely not good enough.

[user3169](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/73982/20213) is absolutely correct.

Yes, your sentence:

> I am interviewing for a job at ABC company.

is equivalent to

> I am interviewing with ABC company for a job.

But, are you the interviewer or the interviewee?

As [csjacobs24](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/73979/20213) said, it really depends on the context.

Take note:

> 1. I am ***taking*** an Interview at the ABC company. ***or*** I am ***conducting*** an Interview at the ABC company.
> 2. I will be ***giving*** an Interview at the ABC company. ***or*** I am being interviewed by the ABC company(Interviewers).

The first sentence means that **you** are the Interviewer. While the second sentence means that you are the interviewee, or being interviewed.

---

Also, have a look at what the Ngram says
[image]

Comment: You have a lot of good stuff in this answer, but I'm not sure I like that bit about _giving_ and _taking_ an interview. (I'd be more likely to say [conducting an interview](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=giving+an+interview%2Cconducting+an+interview&year_start=1950&year_end=2000) or [being interviewed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taking+an+interview%2Cbeing+interviewed&year_start=1950&year_end=2000)). I'm not saying that *give* and *take* are wrong, but they do sound a little awkward to me.

Answer (score 9):

I don't blame you for being confused.  This is an oddity of the English language.  "Interviewing" for a job can mean either giving the interview or being interviewed.  The only way to tell what the speaker means is from context.

So both of your sentences are correct, and so is "If you are interviewing for a teaching job..."

Comment: Hi csjacobs24. So,  the meaning of "I am interviewing for a job at ABC company" is equivalent to "I am interviewing with ABC company for a job", am I right?

Comment: @kitty - That's right. Moreover, many times, people will omit the phrase "for a job": _I am interviewing with ABC tomorrow._ The fact that it's a job interview is often implicit.

Answer (score 3):

They have a somewhat different meaning.

> He **will be interviewing** for a job tomorrow.

This is from the point of view of "he". I just says he will go to an interview. We don't know who is interviewing or even if it will happen.

> He **is being interviewed** for a job this morning.

This is from the point of view of the interviewers. And the interview is roughly in the present.